# Codeigniter session language - default language

Tags: php, codeigniter

This is the [website](http://www.rabassedacs.com)

I'm using this script to use 2 languages on the site (user_agents.php file):

```
<?php
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller {
     public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        parse_str($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'], $_GET);

        if(!$this->session->userdata('lang') && !isset($_GET['lang']) && isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'])){
            $lang = substr($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'], 0, 2);
            $this->session->set_userdata('lang' , $lang);
        }else{
            if(isset($_GET['lang'])){
                if($_GET['lang'] == 'es' || $_GET['lang'] == 'ca'){
                    $this->session->set_userdata('lang' , $_GET['lang']);
                }else{
                    $this->session->set_userdata('lang' , 'ca');
                }
            }
        }
        $this->lang->load('site', $this->session->userdata('lang'));

    }
}
```

I'm having **two issues**:

1. If you are on Homepage and change it to "Catala" language, it changes the URL, but if you click on any menu item it gets you to the page but without the `?lang=ca`... It just opens the section in Spanish, which is the default language. So basically it seems the **session language is not working** as it is not passed after you enter any section.
2. The second issue is that if your browser main language is english the website opens in that language (showing no menu images which loads depending on `spanish` or `catala` language) instead of opening in the default which is already set like this on `config.php` file:

   $config['language'] = 'spanish';

Can someone help me out with this two problems?

Sessions at `config.php`:

```
$config['sess_cookie_name']     = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration']      = 7200;
$config['sess_expire_on_close'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_encrypt_cookie']  = FALSE;
$config['sess_use_database']    = FALSE;
$config['sess_table_name']      = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip']        = FALSE;
$config['sess_match_useragent'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_time_to_update']  = 300;
```

Comment: Unable to load the requested language file: language/ja/site_lang.php

Comment: /lanjuage/ja ? Where do you see that? I'm not loading any "ja" language :S

Comment: I copied and pasted that from the error on your site.

Comment: The error is still there. Looks like you might have a typo somewhere.

Comment: I think it's loading by default the language from the browser's accepted languages, for me it attempted to load `language/fr/site_lang.php` since my browser it set for fr-CA. @codek, I think you should first look if the language set in. `HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE` is managed by your app, because it might fail as it did for me and Kenzo.

Comment: First, your language set in `config.php` should be like `$config['language'] = 'es';` according to your convention (query string)  Is your site_lang.php loaded elsewhere before being loaded in this controller ? (config/autoload for instance ?)

Comment: @MaxiWheat Changed to language 'es' (nothing happened). In my config it has `$config['language'] = 'es';` and in my autoload `$autoload['language'] = array();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your session library working? can u check by setting a session value and and then printing it. I have checked your site. When `lang` GET variable is provided it works as expected because the images to your home page has the correct `prefix`(en,es,ca), but when it's not provided then the default `en_` prefix is assumed. I suggest you to turn on your error reporting or check the error log.

I suggest you to do the following things to enable and check if session is working properly.

Go to `/application/config/autoload.php`, find the line starting with and `$autoload['libraries']` and see whether session is autoloaded. it would look like this

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database','session');
```

Then in your core controller (MY_Controller) do check the following:

```
$this->session->set_userdata('test','Hello World');
echo $this->session->userdata('test'); exit();
```

If `Hello World` is printed then we can say that session is working. Please let me know your response on this.
[Updated after chat with client ]

Solution: The native session library doesn't seems to be working properly. The sessions are lost on page refresh. So i added `native PHP session` library from [here](https://github.com/appleboy/CodeIgniter-Native-Session) and the problem was solved.

Comment: In `autoload.php` I have: `$autoload['libraries'] = array('session');`. I made the check by pasting your code and it printed `Hello World`, so session is working...

Comment: yeah, I put the code in the online version. Please, can you remove the link cause it will get to google... thanks!

Comment: Ah sorry, I just tried, see that it worked and removed. I have just added it again. Reload the site

Comment: K. i have seen it. would you please echo `$this->session->userdata('lang')` with out exit

Comment: but its not echoing any thing. Try `echo "Heloo". $this->session->userdata('lang')` so that i can identify it from source

Comment: The session is not updated with any values, thats your problem. Check there is no value even if you call with link=ca or es GET varaible. the session is not outputting any value. Simply saying the session is not being set at all

Comment: Could you please echo once more like echo `$this->session->userdata('lang')."Heloo";`

Comment: No its not echoing anything

Comment: i think that your lang session is not been set at all.Please check by echoing some thing in your if else conditions and check whether the session is really been set...

Comment: I'm echoing "es langauge" or "ca language" depending on which one is selected. it seems that the `if` are working.

Comment: but what about the session? after setting try printing it in the very nest line with your current echo

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you are saying to do... :S

Comment: now you print `ca language` in your if loop, in that condition you are also setting the session, right. just try echoing the session after setting its value without removing the echoing of `ca language`.

Comment: k try printing all the seesion `print_r($this->session->all_userdata());`

Comment: take page source and see the `user_data` array is null. K do one thing   inside the if conditions statically set the session like `$this->session->set_userdata('mylang','ca');` and then print the sesion. Also please let me see the output. Also are you sure that the `Hello World` session test really worked

Comment: I can give you access to the site if you want to check. I think would save lot of time for both of us

Comment: k. my mail id is nouphaltklm@gmail.com

Comment: Sent you the details, thanks for taking the time to help me man!

Comment: Your FTp is not valid. i can't check

Comment: Hiii @codek are you there. i think i found the problem. Please use native PHP sessions. Check the website.....

Comment: Hi Nouphal. Yeah man, it's working !!! Thank you very much!! Give you the bounty. Will keep in mind about the PHP native sessions.

Comment: In firefox there seems a problem though but don't worry, I will check it out

Comment: It seems there is a problem in firefox with the images and content on `sobre nosotros` pages, in chrome works fine. I'm checking what's the problem with the browser.

Comment: let me check. 5 minutes.

Comment: No, look what I get on firefox: http://rabassedacs.com/1.png It seems that it is not getting a default language

Comment: first set `lang=es` no default lang is set, then check. Once you set the language then everything will be ok

Comment: do you want the default language to be set?

Comment: It is already set like that. I set Spanish as default on config.php `$config['language'] = 'es';` Do you think that's the problem with firefox?

Comment: no the default language would be `en` because `HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE` gets the language from the request header sent by the browser. Normally it would be english

Comment: Yeah it is a problem of that. I put in firefox url `http://rabassedacs.com/?lang=ca` and it does open the web with the images

Comment: do you want to set the language to es if accept language is english?

Comment: Yeah I want to set the default language always as `es` (spanish) So I don't get the error with firefox and for example with the Ipad that has `en` as default

Comment: K. Setted default to es. Have a good day... Thanks for the patience

Answer (score 0):

When viewing the website in Chrome the images are not being displayed. My locale is en, and it looks as if it is matching the locale correctly and obviously there are no images that match the locale.

[image]

Perhaps the issue could be to do with the locale that is being returned from the browser? If you are using an Android device you could enable [remote debugging](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/remote-debugging) within Chrome to better understand the locale which is being sent.

Answer (score 0):

I think it might be useful that you set the language in the config, try this :

```
<?php
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller {
    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        parse_str($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'], $_GET);

        if(!$this->session->userdata('lang') && !isset($_GET['lang']) && isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'])){
            $lang = substr($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'], 0, 2);                
        }else{
            if(isset($_GET['lang'])){
                if($_GET['lang'] == 'es' || $_GET['lang'] == 'ca'){
                    $lang = $_GET['lang'];
                }else{
                    $lang = 'ca';
                }
            }
        }

        $this->session->set_userdata('lang' , $lang);
        $this->config->set_item('language', $lang);
        $this->lang->load('site', $this->session->userdata('lang'));

    }
}
```

Comment: I changed it to this but I don't see any difference, still same problems. Thanks!

Comment: @codek Is the session library autoloaded in your autoload ? (I think that yes otherwise it would crash). Can you post the configuration for your sessions which are located in `application/config/config.php` ? It should begin with `$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';` or something like this

Comment: @codek An other point, is your MY_Controller loaded correctly by your controllers (inherited) ? Does your `config.php` contain `$config['subclass_prefix'] = 'MY_';` ?

Comment: Updated the question with the session of config.php. My `config.php` does contains the following: `$config['subclass_prefix'] = 'MY_';`

Answer (score 0):

Are you autoloading the session library? If the answer is no, then you have to load it before you can do any manipulation with it.

```
$this->load->library('session');
```

So try

```
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller {
    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();

        $this->load->library('session'); // Loading the session library

        parse_str($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'], $_GET);

        if(!$this->session->userdata('lang') && !isset($_GET['lang']) && isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'])){
            $lang = substr($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'], 0, 2);
            $this->session->set_userdata('lang' , $lang);
        }else{
            if(isset($_GET['lang'])){
                if($_GET['lang'] == 'es' || $_GET['lang'] == 'ca'){
                    $this->session->set_userdata('lang' , $_GET['lang']);
                }else{
                    $this->session->set_userdata('lang' , 'ca');
                }
            }
        }
        $this->lang->load('site', $this->session->userdata('lang'));

    }
}
```

Comment: Changed it. I don't see any difference... thanks anyway!